# Comprehensive list of RTL pragma directive triggers

Tags: vhdl, verilog

In verilog and VHDL RTL commands to tools can be given as pragma directives as pseudo comments.  I want to avoid using any of these pragma directives in my real comments, so what I'd like to have is a comprehensive list of pragma directive triggers.  Ones I know about are:

```
-- pragma
// synthesis
-- synopsys
```

Comment: I agree that this is a good source of information.  The problem is that there are several tools in the flow.  Whilst one of them might ignore a trigger, another one might use that trigger.  Whilst it is not an onerous task to go through all the tools currently in the flow, I wanted to know if there was a standard set of them.  Also IP companies might not know the flow the code is going to be implemented using.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a comprehensive list here:

http://www.sigasi.com/content/list-known-vhdl-metacomment-pragmas

As long as you don't have a comment starting with the trigger, i.e., `-- <trigger> ...`, you should be safe.

For example, when using Altera Quartus, avoid comments such as

`-- altera code below`,

while

`-- The following is for altera.`

would be fine.

Comment: I saw that list, however it clearly didn't list at least two triggers that I'm aware of, so I thought it couldn't be that comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably find several lists like this, but I doubt any of them are complete. (The one zennehoy posted is missing `-- psl`, among others.) Even if there is a complete list somewhere you never know what pragmas vendors will add in the future, thus you can never be sure.

If you want your code to be as portable as possible you should probably avoid starting comments with common vendor/tool names like zennehoy suggests (such as synopsys, altera, xilinx, lattice, modelsim, etc.) Other than that I'd say you just have to take your chances.

Comment: @WestHamster IEEE has already suggested a way to do pragma directives with attributes, `(* attribute *)` . See IEEE1364-2001 section 2.8. Attributes were included in over to IEEE1800. It is a cleaner then putting the pragmas in comments. However, I haven't seen much push from venders or requests form customers to have it properly implemented. There is also the issue with a lot of old Verilog code that is dependent on the old method. A clean solution will have slow adoptions.